# Prefix vs Postfix and table made of array?

Tags: c++, arrays, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

Can you please explain this code, keeping in mind that the person who wrote it was using it to teach me the difference between prefix and postfix incrementations

```
int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 3;`enter code here`
    const int COLUMNS = 3;`enter code here`
    char board[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{'O', 'X', 'O'}, {' ', 'X', 'X'}, {'X', 'O', 'O'}};
    cout << "Here’s the tic-tac-toe board:\n";




    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while ( i < ROWS) {
        cout<<board[i][j];

        j++;

        if (j >= COLUMNS) {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That may have been the intention, but it completely fails to teach any such thing, as it doesn't contain any prefix operators at all, and as you could convert all the postfix operators to prefix without altering the semantics of the program.

Comment: oh alright i understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't seem to show any difference between postfix and prefix incrementation, anyway this is how it works:

**POSTFIXED**

```cpp
int x = 10;
cout<< (x++); //output: 10
//now x is 11
```

**PREFIXED**

```cpp
int x = 10;
cout<< (++x); //output: 11 (and x is already 11)
```

Basically, the postfixed increment will only show its effects after the operation where it is called. The prefixed increment will shot its effect immediatly, so that the incremented value is already used in the command where it is called.

If the increment is isolated, that is, not used inside an operation, it's basically the same thing:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)   =   for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

---

About your code, it just walks through all slots of the matrix in this order:

```
(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)
```

When `j >= COLUMNS`, it means that `(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)` were already visited, so you can go to the next row by doing `i++` (`i` represents the row index) because all the columns of row `i` were already visited. Doing `j = 0` resets the column to the beginning (`j` represents the column index).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understood it now. Could you please explain what's happening in the code above as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code simply works it way from `board[0][0]` to `board[2][2]` outputting the current `X`s and `O`s from the array using the variables `i` and `j` in `board[i][j]` to add `1` to `j` until `j == ROWS` (`j == 3`) and resets `j` to zero and moves to the next row -- and repeats until you run out of rows -- the board having been fully printed.